# How to filter the outside of an element but inside its parent?

Tags: html, css

I have two element like this.

```css
.parent {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6b/Icecat1-300x300.svg/2048px-Icecat1-300x300.svg.png");
   background-position: center; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 3px pink solid;
}
.children {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 3px blue solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children"></div>
</div>
```

I want a way to filter the outside of children `filter-outside: opacity(0.5);` but inside of parent

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: Just like this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTP7v.png, filter the outside of the blue border div to opacity 0.5

Comment: Is the child always exactly centered on the parent?

Comment: @AHaworth yes, it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with filter. What you can do is a a little trick to have the same effect. You can add a shadow to the parent with the property inset.
By adding the line `box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 47px #ffffff8a;` to the style of your `.parent`.
But keep in mind that this is a little trick, if the picture change size for example this won't really work well

```css
.parent {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6b/Icecat1-300x300.svg/2048px-Icecat1-300x300.svg.png");
   background-position: center; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 3px pink solid;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 47px #ffffff8a;
}
.children {
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 3px blue solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children"></div>
</div>
```

What you could try, is adding the shadow to the child and add an `overflow:hidden;` to the parent. In this case, if the picture change size, this will continue working.

```css
.parent {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6b/Icecat1-300x300.svg/2048px-Icecat1-300x300.svg.png");
   background-position: center; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 3px pink solid;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.children {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 100000px #ffffff8c;
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 3px blue solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children"></div>
</div>
```

In summary, the best way to do that would be with the `box-shadow` property set to the child, as in the last snippet. But do not forget to add the `overflow:hidden;` to the parent or the shadow will not stop at the boundaries of the parent div

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
background: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/01/Figure_in_Manga_style.png") transparent no-repeat center center / cover;
    width: 100vw;height: 250px;
  display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center;
}

span:nth-child(1) {
width:100%;opacity:0.5;height:100%;
position:absolute;top:0;left:0;
background:white;z-index:0;
clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, 25% 100%, 25% 25%, 75% 25%, 75% 75%, 25% 75%, 25% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is an acceptable idea but quite complicated with the clip-path, the other answer is much easier to achieve what I want

Comment: Sure np you don't have to specify this, you can just choose one answer as the one that helps *you* the better in that situation, and then the community will upvote and downvote answers as they see fit. That's actually how this website works.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a copy of the un-obscured background:

```css
.parent {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6b/Icecat1-300x300.svg/2048px-Icecat1-300x300.svg.png");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 3px pink solid;
  position: relative;
}

.children {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 3px blue solid;
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6b/Icecat1-300x300.svg/2048px-Icecat1-300x300.svg.png");
  background-size: 300px 300px;
  background-position: center center;
  z-index: 2;
}

.parent::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children"></div>
</div>
```